# JPA Hibernate ManyToMany, cascading and FK

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, join

I'm converting my project's database management from JDBC MySQL to JPA Hibernate, the database should stay the same.
(From a simple Jersey API to Spring with Hibernate api).

There are tables for **Company**, **Customer** and **Coupons**.
Each *Company* can manage ***many coupons*** and each *Customer* can also 'purchase' ***many coupons***.

Therefore, I have a join table named **company_coupon** and another table called **customer_coupon**.
When a *Company* is deleted, if the *Coupon* isn't owned by any other *Company* –thus has no manager– the Coupon is deleted, and as a result so are all the relationships (**company_coupon** and **customer_coupon**).

When a Customer is deleted, the relationship in coupon_customer should also be deleted.

This seems to me like a *OneToMany* relationship since the **Coupon** doesn't have to know who his owners are, (A company manages coupons, A customer owns coupons), but everything I found regarding JPA Hibernate and join tables points to this being a *ManyToMany* relatiopship, which confuses me.

***How can I define what I described in JPA Hibernate?***

---

Also, I used to have archive tables for everything while deleting them from the original tables. which could make handling stuff messy.
So I've added a '***removed***' field to each and configured the entity's delete function to change it's removed state to true by:

```
@SQLDelete(sql = 
        "UPDATE " + TableHelper.TBL_COMPANY 
        + " SET " + TableHelper.REMOVED + " = true"
        + " WHERE " + TableHelper.COMPANY_KEY + " = ?")
```

Now, If you attempt to delete a company, only the '***removed***' value is changed.
But I want all of the coupons that are left unmanaged –without a relationship to any existing, unarchived company– to become archived aswell.

Really complex process just to manage the data.. any idead how to do it efficiently?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think this delete statement will be similar with update statement. So when you define SqlDelete it will not work

Answer (score 0):

> everything I found regarding JPA Hibernate and join tables points to this being a ManyToMany relatiopship

'Each Company can manage **many** coupons' and 'if the Coupon isn't owned by any other Company (= a coupon may belong to **more than one** company)' hint at the fact that `Coupon - Company` is a *many-to-many* association. The fact that 'the Coupon doesn't have to know who his owners are' only tells you that it should probably be a *unidirectional* association.

> When a Customer is deleted, the relationship in coupon_customer should also be deleted.

This will happen automatically, provided that `Customer` is the owning side of the relationship (and since you want to make it a unidirectional association anyway, you don't really have any other options). Simply declare `Customer.coupons` as a many-to-many association as follows:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "customer_coupon", joinColumns = ..., inverseJoinColumns = ...)
private Set<Coupon> coupons;
```

> When a Company is deleted, if the Coupon isn't owned by any other Company –thus has no manager– the Coupon is deleted, and as a result so are all the relationships (company_coupon and customer_coupon).

JPA will not take care of that for you. Your app will need to detect and handle such a scenario as part of its business logic (this might sound like a potential performance issue, but then again, how often is a company actually going to be deleted?)

Comment: **1)** Once I execute `Company.coupons.remove(c)` is that going to automatically remove `Coupon c` from the database, or just the relationship. **2)** So soft `DELETE`, _while managing join tables_, should also be handled as part of business logic?

Comment: (1) Only the relationship will be removed, (2) I never used `@SQLDelete`, but if you find that it works well with your use case, I guess there's no reason not to use it